# I am working on wordpress theme-development but walker menu is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

That's the result: WordPress walker menu not working. It's saying:

> Warning: Attempt to read property "link_after" on int in C:\Users\Emon\Local Sites\theme-development\app\public\wp-content\themes\Theme Development\functions.php on line 82

*([Screenshot of the repeated error message with display errors in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi6BW.png))*

I cant figure out what to change in my code:

```php
// Walker Menu Properties (Not Working)
function bobcat_nav_description($item_output, $item, $args)
{
    if (!empty($item->description)) {
        $item_output = str_replace($args-> link_after . '</a>', '<span class="walker_nav">' . $item->description . '</span>' . $args->link_after . '</a>', $item_output);
    }
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'bobcat_nav_description', 10, 3);
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/ - the callback function will be passed _four_ parameters, yours is accepting only three. What you are accessing via `$args` in your function, is actually the `$depth` parameter, and that one _is_ an integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom walker menu for wordpress not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243749/custom-walker-menu-for-wordpress-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

What [@CBroe commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76753407/i-am-working-on-wordpress-theme-development-but-walker-menu-is-not-working#comment135314373_76753407); when [adding a callback to a filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/), which is done with [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/):

```php
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'bobcat_nav_description', 10, 3);
```

The callback *bobcat_nav_description()* has to match the *parameters* for the filter hook, the first parameter ['walker_nav_menu_start_el'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/).

This requires you review the hook specification in the WordPress manual for its *parameters*:

```php
apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', string $item_output, WP_Post $menu_item, int $depth, stdClass $args )
```

and compare with your code:

```php
function bobcat_nav_description($item_output, $item, $args)
```

you can immediately see how the arguments are different, so make them the same:

```php
function bobcat_nav_description(string $item_output, WP_Post $menu_item, int $depth, stdClass $args)
```

As you can see, those are all parameters from apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', ...) but the first one (which is the string of the filter/hook name.

It is that these parameters will be forwarded to your callback, so it must accept them with the same types and names.

- In case of trouble with hooks/filters, check the docs if the wiring is (still) correct.
- The starting point is the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/)